# Font problems with pdftex

Tags: fonts, texlive

I have

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
%\usepackage[sups]{XCharter}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum} %

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

When I run pdflatex on this file, I get an error:

```
pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.
```

If I uncomment the `\usepackage[sups]{XCharter}` line, I get this error:

```
Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `t2aenc.def' not found.
```

A google search shows this has something to do with cyrillic, but that's obviously not relevant.  The problem persists after a complete reinstall of texlive, and it started after an upgrade to Debian 10.

I'm not sure whether this is a texlive or a Debian problem and should be reported as a bug to Debian.  Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate issues here:

1. If you want to use microtype with the default Computer Modern font family, you can install the `cm-super` package:

   ```
   apt install cm-super
   ```

   for Debian 10 (requires using `sudo` or another mean to gain root privileges). The 
   `cm-super` package replaces bitmap fonts by their PostScript equivalents, which are scalable.
2. The `XCharter` package unconditionally requires `fontenc` with `T2A` option (among a few others). So if you want to use the package, you'd have to install the support for Cyrillics in LaTeX:

   ```
   apt install texlive-lang-cyrillic
   ```

   should do that in Debian 10.

Comment: Thanks, it works now.  But I'm still a bit puzzled.  I know for certain that I didn't have either cm-super or texlive-lang-cyrillic installed, but the document still compiled without any problems before the update.  Moreover, if texlive-lang-cyrillic is not available, I get the fatal error, but the document still compiles fine.  I wonder what changed with the update.

Comment: Without `cm-super` you just can't use microtype fully, but the error isn't fatal, it's just a warning. On the other hand, `fontenc` makes error about `T2A` fatal, but since you don't use any Cyrillics in the text, you can ignore the error. Though you can't avoid it without installing `texlive-lang-cyrillic`. It's just how the `XCharter` package written.

Comment: But that just makes it even more mysterious why all of it worked before (no warning by microtype, no fatal error by XCharter).

Comment: I don't have older TeXLive at the moment, but I guess that Cyrillic support was added to XCharter only recently. As for microtype I'm not sure why there weren't any warning earlier.