# `sudo apt install texlive-lang-cyrillic` breaks existing fonts & packages

Tags: texlive, installing, cyrillic, installing-fonts

My LaTeX install was working fine. Then [someone](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507445) told me to run `apt install texlive-lang-cyrillic` to allow me to use **XCharter**. Now, some packages appear missing like **authblk**: `LaTeX Error: File 'authblk.sty' not found.`

How do I recover my install? I'm hoping it is a path issue... What a pain.

Comment: were you using the debian texlive installed via apt previously or were you runningthe texlive from tug  maintaind via tlmgr rather than apt. what does `type --all pdflatex` report on the terminal?

Comment: TL/DR: Yes I had 2 installs... Before I saw your reply, I ran `sudo apt remove texlive*` thinking to do a clean install. Then, on a whim, I tried compiling, and of course, it worked! because this `apt` version was a second install, and the first with `tlmgr` as you suggest (described [here](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) for future readers...). As always, thanks!

Comment: To answer your question: `type --all pdflatex` now returns: `pdflatex is /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`, but presumably there used to be a second option.

Comment: yes I was expecting to see both /usr/bin/pdflatex and the one you have with the answer being to delete one of them:-)